C#.NET XML Serialization: XMLAttribute is not setting NameSpace and only Password Element within UserName Object is having Attribute
I am trying to generate this Soap XML:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
                <wsse:UsernameToken>
                    <wsse:Username>TestUser02</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password1</wsse:Password>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
            </wsse:Security>
            <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
             <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>1</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
            </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <bsvc:Get_Customers_Request bsvc:version="v42.0">
             <bsvc:Request_References>
                <bsvc:Customer_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
                   <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Customer_ID">100001</bsvc:ID>
                </bsvc:Customer_Reference>
             </bsvc:Request_References>
             <bsvc:Response_Group>
                <bsvc:Include_Reference>0</bsvc:Include_Reference>
                <bsvc:Include_Customer_Data>0</bsvc:Include_Customer_Data>
                <bsvc:Include_Customer_Balance>1</bsvc:Include_Customer_Balance>
                <bsvc:Include_Customer_Activity_Detail>0</bsvc:Include_Customer_Activity_Detail>
             </bsvc:Response_Group>
          </bsvc:Get_Customers_Request>
       </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

But I am getting this XML using my code Below:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
          <wsse:UsernameToken Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
            <wsse:Username>TestUser02</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>Password1</wsse:Password>
          </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
          <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>1</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
        </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
      </soapenv:Header>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <bsvc:Get_Customers_Request version="v42.0">
          <bsvc:Request_References>
            <bsvc:Customer_Reference Descriptor="?">
              <bsvc:ID type="Customer_ID">100001</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Customer_Reference>
          </bsvc:Request_References>
          <bsvc:Response_Group>
            <bsvc:Include_Reference>0</bsvc:Include_Reference>
            <bsvc:Include_Customer_Data>0</bsvc:Include_Customer_Data>
            <bsvc:Include_Customer_Balance>1</bsvc:Include_Customer_Balance>
            <bsvc:Include_Customer_Activity_Detail>0</bsvc:Include_Customer_Activity_Detail>
          </bsvc:Response_Group>
        </bsvc:Get_Customers_Request>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

This is the C# Code I have:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WorkDayAPI
{
    [XmlRoot("Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement("Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Body")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement("Security", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public Security Security { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Workday_Common_Header", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public WorkdayCommonHeader WorkdayCommonHeader { get; set; }
    }

    public class Security
    {
        [XmlAttribute("mustUnderstand", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public string MustUnderstand { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("UsernameToken", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
    }

    public class UsernameToken
    {
        [XmlElement("Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Password", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Type")]
        public string PasswordType { get; set; }
    }


    public class WorkdayCommonHeader
    {
        [XmlElement("Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public string IncludeReferenceDescriptorsInResponse { get; set; }
    }

    
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement("Get_Customers_Request", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public GetCustomersRequest GetCustomersRequest { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetCustomersRequest
    {
        [XmlElement("Request_References", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public RequestReferences RequestReferences { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("version", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Response_Group", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public ResponseGroup ResponseGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestReferences
    {
        [XmlElement("Customer_Reference", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public CustomerReference CustomerReference { get; set; }

        
    }

    public class CustomerReference
    {

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Descriptor", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public string Descriptor { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
        public CustomerData CustomerData { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlType(Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
    public class CustomerData
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResponseGroup
    {
        [XmlElement("Include_Reference", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public string IncludeReference { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Include_Customer_Data", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public string IncludeCustomerData { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Include_Customer_Balance", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public string IncludeCustomerBalance { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Include_Customer_Activity_Detail", Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
        public string IncludeCustomerActivityDetail { get; set; }
    }
}

This is how I am setting Namespaces and Assigning Values:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using WorkDayAPI.Input;

namespace WorkDayAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GenerateSoapXmlRequest();

        }

        public static void GenerateSoapXmlRequest()
        {
            // Create the request object and populate it with values
            var soapRequest = new Envelope
            {
                Header = new Header
                {
                    Security = new Security
                    {
                        MustUnderstand = "1",
                        UsernameToken = new UsernameToken
                        {
                            Username = "TestUser02",
                            Password = "Password1",
                            PasswordType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"

                        }
                    },
                    WorkdayCommonHeader = new WorkdayCommonHeader
                    {
                        IncludeReferenceDescriptorsInResponse = "1"
                    }
                },
                Body = new Body
                {
                    GetCustomersRequest = new GetCustomersRequest
                    {
                        Version = "v42.0",
                        RequestReferences = new RequestReferences
                        {
                            CustomerReference = new CustomerReference
                            {
                                Descriptor = "?",
                                CustomerData = new CustomerData
                                {
                                    Type = "Customer_ID",
                                    ID = "100001"
                                }
                            }
                            
                        },
                        ResponseGroup = new ResponseGroup
                        {
                            IncludeReference = "0",
                            IncludeCustomerData = "0",
                            IncludeCustomerBalance = "1",
                            IncludeCustomerActivityDetail = "0"
                        }
}
                }
            };

            // Prepare the namespaces with appropriate prefixes
            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            namespaces.Add("bsvc", "urn:com.workday/bsvc");
            namespaces.Add("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

            // Create an XmlSerializer instance for the Envelope class
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

            // Create a StringWriter to hold the serialized XML
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                // Create an XmlWriterSettings object to control XML formatting
                var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                    Indent = true,
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = true
                };

                // Create an XmlWriter with the settings and namespaces
                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlSettings))
                {
                    // Serialize the object to XML, passing the namespaces
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, soapRequest, namespaces);
                }

                // Get the generated XML as a string
                string soapXml = stringWriter.ToString();

                // Print the serialized XML to the console
                Console.WriteLine(soapXml);

                // Optionally, save the XML to a file
                File.WriteAllText("SoapRequest.xml", soapXml);
            }
        }

        
    }
}

How to Fix that Type Attribute in the password?
How to set the Namespace of bsvc in the Body Attribute?
Here is the Comparison Difference between Required XML vs generated XML:
ComparisonPic:[![enter image description here][1]][1]


Create a class for password that replicates the exact same logic as class CustomerData.

Are you using Visual Studio? If so you can Generate Class From JSON or XML in Visual Studio .
To create the classes from XML do the following:

Open Visual Studio

Create new Project (File => New Project => ...)

Create new class (Project => Add Class...) name: Envelope.cs

Highlight the XML, right-click, and select Copy

In VS menu, click Edit

Select Paste special

Select Paste XML As Classes


You'll get the following:
// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{

    private EnvelopeHeader headerField;

    private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public EnvelopeHeader Header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public EnvelopeBody Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bodyField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeHeader
{

    private Security securityField;

    private Workday_Common_Header workday_Common_HeaderField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" +
        "")]
    public Security Security
    {
        get
        {
            return this.securityField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.securityField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
    public Workday_Common_Header Workday_Common_Header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.workday_Common_HeaderField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.workday_Common_HeaderField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" +
    "")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" +
    "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Security
{

    private SecurityUsernameToken usernameTokenField;

    private byte mustUnderstandField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public SecurityUsernameToken UsernameToken
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usernameTokenField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usernameTokenField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public byte mustUnderstand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mustUnderstandField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mustUnderstandField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" +
    "")]
public partial class SecurityUsernameToken
{

    private string usernameField;

    private SecurityUsernameTokenPassword passwordField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usernameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usernameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public SecurityUsernameTokenPassword Password
    {
        get
        {
            return this.passwordField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.passwordField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" +
    "")]
public partial class SecurityUsernameTokenPassword
{

    private string typeField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Workday_Common_Header
{

    private byte include_Reference_Descriptors_In_ResponseField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response
    {
        get
        {
            return this.include_Reference_Descriptors_In_ResponseField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.include_Reference_Descriptors_In_ResponseField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeBody
{

    private Get_Customers_Request get_Customers_RequestField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
    public Get_Customers_Request Get_Customers_Request
    {
        get
        {
            return this.get_Customers_RequestField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.get_Customers_RequestField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Get_Customers_Request
{

    private Get_Customers_RequestRequest_References request_ReferencesField;

    private Get_Customers_RequestResponse_Group response_GroupField;

    private string versionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Get_Customers_RequestRequest_References Request_References
    {
        get
        {
            return this.request_ReferencesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.request_ReferencesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Get_Customers_RequestResponse_Group Response_Group
    {
        get
        {
            return this.response_GroupField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.response_GroupField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
public partial class Get_Customers_RequestRequest_References
{

    private Get_Customers_RequestRequest_ReferencesCustomer_Reference customer_ReferenceField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Get_Customers_RequestRequest_ReferencesCustomer_Reference Customer_Reference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customer_ReferenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.customer_ReferenceField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
public partial class Get_Customers_RequestRequest_ReferencesCustomer_Reference
{

    private Get_Customers_RequestRequest_ReferencesCustomer_ReferenceID idField;

    private string descriptorField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Get_Customers_RequestRequest_ReferencesCustomer_ReferenceID ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string Descriptor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptorField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptorField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
public partial class Get_Customers_RequestRequest_ReferencesCustomer_ReferenceID
{

    private string typeField;

    private uint valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public uint Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvc")]
public partial class Get_Customers_RequestResponse_Group
{

    private byte include_ReferenceField;

    private byte include_Customer_DataField;

    private byte include_Customer_BalanceField;

    private byte include_Customer_Activity_DetailField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Include_Reference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.include_ReferenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.include_ReferenceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Include_Customer_Data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.include_Customer_DataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.include_Customer_DataField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Include_Customer_Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return this.include_Customer_BalanceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.include_Customer_BalanceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Include_Customer_Activity_Detail
    {
        get
        {
            return this.include_Customer_Activity_DetailField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.include_Customer_Activity_DetailField = value;
        }
    }
}


Usage:
// Create the request object and populate it with values
var soapRequest = new Envelope()
{
    Body = new EnvelopeBody()
    {
        Get_Customers_Request = new Get_Customers_Request()
        {
            Request_References = new Get_Customers_RequestRequest_References()
            {
                Customer_Reference = new Get_Customers_RequestRequest_ReferencesCustomer_Reference()
                {
                    Descriptor = "?",
                    ID = new Get_Customers_RequestRequest_ReferencesCustomer_ReferenceID()
                    {
                        type = "Customer_ID",
                        Value = 100001
                    }
                }
            },
            Response_Group = new Get_Customers_RequestResponse_Group() 
            {
                Include_Customer_Activity_Detail = 0,
                Include_Customer_Balance = 1,
                Include_Customer_Data = 0,
                Include_Reference = 0
            },
            version = "v42.0"
        }
    },
    Header = new EnvelopeHeader()
    {
        Security = new Security()
        {
            mustUnderstand = 1,
            UsernameToken = new SecurityUsernameToken()
            {
                Username = "TestUser02",
                Password = new SecurityUsernameTokenPassword()
                {
                    Type = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText",
                    Value = "Password1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};


If you're interested in learning how to create the classes yourself , some of my other posts show how to do it.
Additional Resources:

Serialization Ordering


First problem is solved by Making password as XMLText and PasswordType as XMLAttribute inside Password Class, then it geenrated XML correctly. Still not getting Namespace of BSVC Inside Body Attributes:
public class UsernameToken
    {
        [XmlElement("Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Password")]
        public PasswordData Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class PasswordData
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Type")]
        public string PasswordType { get; set; }
    }

